# How to build in 'maintenance mode' in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using latest codeigniter and I need to create a flag (ideally in the config) when turned to 'true', all pages display a 'maintenance mode' message instead of executing their controller code.

What is the best/simplest practice for doing this?

Comment: I, personally, think that it's better for you to make a module which save maintenance mode state on database. So you can dynamically switch it on and off from your application.

Comment: @tereško i'm new to mvc and want to ensure I go down the correct route of setting this sort of functionality up.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Extend the CI_Controller by putting a new file in your core directory called MY_Controller.

In this file's constructor, do something like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if($this->config->item('maintenance_mode') == TRUE) {
        $this->load->view('maintenance_view');
        die();
    }
}
```

Let all controllers in your app inherit from that class.

Comment: Your (safe) live website just turned very unsafe :P. But this would be the way as the OP asked, so +1 :)

Comment: @Allendar Can you explain how this change makes the site unsafe?

Comment: Considering the website is in "maintenance" mode, and you allow people to still access it (even tho it's not commonly known to the outside world) it might still pose a threat if you test code and other people might be able to access it. Won't be much of a worry, but still.

Comment: How are people 'still access[ing] it' when EVERY request dies after loading the maintenance view?

Comment: I have tried implementing this and when maintenance mode is set to TRUE, I get a blank page, despite my maintenance view file having content. If I remove the "die();" command, I see the text above the content of my home page, so the view file is OK. Why do I only see a blank white page?

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution, however for those who are receiving a blank page (like me), if you set the 3rd parameter to TRUE, you can retrieve the HTML and then echo it.

    $content = $this->load->view('maintenance_view, '', TRUE);
    echo $content;

Answer (score 35):

Here my solution, works fine for me:

The below will call maintanance.php immediately, so you can go ahead and break your  CI code without the world seeing it.

Also allow you to add you own ip address so that you can still access the site for testing etc.

In index.php add at top:

```
$maintenance = false; ## set to true to enable

if ($maintenance)
{
    if (isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'your_ip')
    {
        ##do nothing
    } else
    {

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1); ## to debug your maintenance view

        require_once 'maintenance.php'; ## call view
        return;
        exit();

    }
}
```

Add file Maintanance.php in same folder as index.php (or update path above):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Maintenance</title>

        <style>
            body {
                width:500px;
                margin:0 auto;
                text-align: center;
                color:blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <img src="images/home_page_logo.png">

        <h1><p>Sorry for the inconvenience while we are upgrading. </p>
            <p>Please revisit shortly</p>
        </h1>
        <div></div>

        <img src="images/under-maintenance.gif"   >

    </body>
</html>
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Retry-After: 3600');
?>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this overall solution, but you cannot send headers *after* your HTML. Headers must be the very first thing you send to the user.

Comment: Thanks Karman! This is the solution I really like as it can implement the maintenance mode before executing any CI codes. +1 more for allowing the developers IP access.

Answer (score 9):

Here my solution, simply, clean and effectively for all urls calls and SEO respects:

---

Add this variables in:
**application/config/config.php**

```
$config['maintenance_mode'] = TRUE;
$config['maintenance_ips'] = array('0.0.0.0', '1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2');
```

---

Add this conditional at the end of: 
**application/config/routes.php**

```
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->config->item('maintenance_ips')) && $this->config->item('maintenance_mode')) {
    $route['default_controller'] = "your_controller/maintenance";
    $route['(:any)'] = "your_controller/maintenance";";
}
```

---

Create method *maintenance* in: 
**application/controllers/*your_controller*.php**

```
function maintenance() {
     $this->output->set_status_header('503'); 
     $this->load->view('maintenance_view');
}
```

---

Create view: 
**application/views/maintenance_view.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Maintenance</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>We apologize but our site is currently undergoing maintenance at this time.</p>
      <p>Please check back later.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I've come up with for creating a maintenance mode.

1. Enable Hooks in the config.php file
2. Create an error_maintenance.php page under errors folder
3. Create a Hook called maintenance
4. In the hooks config setup your hooks call to run on post_controller

### application/errors/error_maintenance.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Maintenance</title>
    <style>Style your page</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>We apologize but our site is currently undergoing maintenance at this time.</p>
    <p>Please check back later.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

### application/hooks/maintenance.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class maintenance
{
   var $CI;    
   public function maintenance()
   {
      $this->CI =& get_instance();
      $this->CI->load->config("config_maintenance");    
      if(config_item("maintenance"))
      {
          $_error =& load_class('Exceptions', 'core');
          echo $_error->show_error("", "", 'error_maintenance', 200);
          exit;
      }
   }
}
```

### application/config/hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller'][] = array(
   'class' => 'maintenance',
   'function' => 'maintenance',
   'filename' => 'maintenance.php',
   'filepath' => 'hooks',
   'params' => array()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this :

1. create auto-loaded libraries which always check maintenance flag on your database.
2. create a module for controlling your application maintenance flag.
3. create a module for redirecting when maintenance mode is on

auto-loaded libraries can contain something like this :

```
class Maintenance_mode {
    function __construct(){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $check_maintenance = $CI->db->select('flag_mode')->get('tbl_settings')->result();
        if($check_maintenance[0]->flag_mode == '1') 
            redirect(site_url('maintenance_mode_controller'));
    }
}
```

next step is to create a controller for maintenance page.

Answer (score 0):

this one works well,

**application/views/vw_maintenance.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Maintenance</title>
        <style>Style your page</style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>We apologize but our site is currently undergoing maintenance at this time.</p>
        <p>Please check back later.</p>
      </body>
    </html>
<?php exit(); ?>
```

the exit() function is very importantn don forget to put it at the bottom, it will prevent all pages from being displayed.

**application/libraries/maintenance.php**

```
class Maintenance{

    private $CI;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        // flag on and off
        $this->flag( $this->CI->uri->segment(1) );

        // get the flag status
        $check_maintenance = $this->CI->db->select('flag_mode')->where(array('setting_name' => 'maintenance'))->get('tbl_settings')->result();

        //display view if true
        if($check_maintenance[0]->flag_mode == '1')
            $this->CI->load->view('vw_maintenance');


    }

    private function flag($command){


        $this->CI->db->where('setting_name', 'evolving');

        switch($command){

            case "activate":                
                $this->CI->db->update('tbl_settings', array('flag_mode' => 1) ); 
            break;

            case "deactivate":
                $this->CI->db->update('tbl_settings', array('flag_mode' => 0) );
                redirect(site_url('/'));
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

autoload the library so it will be check every page load.

now you can activate and deactivate maintenance mode by typing  or

Answer (score 0):

I think this was easy, Just call view on the constructor like below.

comment (site will be live)

```
class home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    //echo $this->load->view('maintenance','',true);exit;
    }
}
```

uncomment (site will be under maintenance)

```
class home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    echo $this->load->view('maintenance','',true);exit;
    }
}
```

And you can use your own "maintenance.php" page under "view" in CI Application.