# I need to down my site when status is changed from admin panel how can i do so any idea anyone?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello All i need to get my site down for maintenance from the admin panel without using any flags. I just want to check the time in the database & my site must be down at that time. is there any solution to that without using cron jobs & maintenance.flag files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a timer in php to bring a website down, you can however do the following:

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15572833/1379394

You can do it like the following **in Codeigniter**

Extend the CI_Controller by putting a new file in your core directory called MY_Controller.

In this file's constructor, do something like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if($this->config->item('maintenance_mode') == TRUE) {
        $this->load->view('maintenance_view');
        die();
    }
}
```

Let all controllers in your app inherit from that class.

Comment: you could use php date and time functions to see if the maintenance mode should be on or not...

Comment: how? tell me. I think the best way is thinking in 'codeigniter' syntax.

Comment: thanks for your answer sonnema , I am definitely going to use this.

Comment: @KeesSonnema you could make to config items, just like ```$this->config->item('maintenance_mode')```, with a start and end time for when the maintenance mode needs to be active.