# How to manage the maintenance state in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have this CI project in which sometimes I need to manage the maintenance state. The maintenance mode should be activated/deactivated and thus the site display either the normal pages or the maintenance page.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572568/how-to-build-in-maintenance-mode-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your core directory create a new controller called MY_Controller.php

In this file you should put this code :

```
public function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();

   if($this->config->item('maintenance_on') == TRUE) {
     $this->load->view('maintenance');
     die();
   }
}
```

All your controllers should inherit this controller in order to work.

Comment: I used that solution so I dont see the problem saying my approach. I dont have the time to search the initial post but i can post what I have on my sites

Comment: You should respect others if you have your own code then post it otherwise link to that post in comment section... What you did is line to line and word to word copy of someone's answer....thats what i am saying :)

Comment: I just told you that I dont remeber the link of initial response ... On the other hand its quicker to give the response which is more handy meaning on my server

Comment: @Arizona2014 Copying someone's work or code ditto is dumb and smells of plagiarism. The least you could have done is followed a bit different approach or at least explained what the code does by commenting.

Comment: And I dont know why you are so afected as I've seen here lots and lots of responses exactly mine and nobody was bothered. Are you that guys advocate or something ?

Comment: I see you doing the same thing here with my post ... bulling my answer just for you to have an activity ... What is to comment in 3 lines of code ? And besides I've said clearly where to put the file and what to do with it .

Comment: @PrahladYeri This isn't exactly "copying" when it's a pretty simple piece of code, it's not like it takes more than 2-3 minutes to come up with yourself.